Spring boot обновление до 3.3.0
Обновил проэкт с spring boot 3.2.6 до 3.3.0
Появилось вот такое сообщение:
[WARN ] 2024-06-06 16:15:14.443 [restartedMain] InitializeUserDetailsBeanManagerConfigurer$InitializeUserDetailsManagerConfigurer - Global AuthenticationManager configured with an AuthenticationProvider bean. UserDetailsService beans will not be used for username/password login. Consider removing the AuthenticationProvider bean. Alternatively, consider using the UserDetailsService in a manually instantiated DaoAuthenticationProvider.

Конфигурация:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final MyUserDetails myUserDetails;    

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(
                auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/token", "/api/v1/refreshToken").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        var provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(myUserDetails);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return provider;
    }
    
}

Не могу понять что мне с этим делать
Куда копать даже не догадываюсь (

Согласно новой версии, AuthenticationProvider может подтягиваться самостоятельно: источник
Решение простое: Удалить создание Bean методом authenticationProvider() (Just delete method of Bean registration)
